# C# Combobox binding to a Dictionary got 1 item when source empty

Tags: c#, dictionary, combobox, bindingsource

I have the following code in a Windows Form

```
Dictionary<String, String> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
ComboBox cbo = new ComboBox();
cbo.DisplayMember = "Key";
cbo.ValueMember = "Value";  // Not used
this.Controls.Add(cbo);
BindingSource bind = new BindingSource(dict, null);
cbo.DataSource = bind;
int count = cbo.Items.Count;
```

Why in my case, count is 1 at the end?

If I put data in the Dictionary, everything is Ok.

**EDIT:**
Solution is in the comment of the answer (until we have better)

Comment: Don't bind to an empty source or else the source itself, read its type will show up. Make the combobox wider and look at the item it shows..:`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary\`2[System.String,System.String]`

Comment: I know the item seems to be the dictionary, the question is why it behave different way depending on the content of the dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try changing the rows:

```
BindingSource bind = new BindingSource(dict, null);
cbo.DataSource = bind;
```

to:

```
BindingSource bind = new BindingSource();
bind.DataSource = dict;
cbo.DataSource = bind;
```

I tried this and the result in `cbo.Items.Count` was 0.

Comment: Same problem, I might need a full reboot

Comment: Same problem after a reboot, the single item in the list seems to be the dictionary itself

Comment: Then you can check if the dict is empty or not, and attach it as a datasource only if there are elements in it.

Comment: this is my patch: bind.DataSource = dict.Any() ? dict : null;, just wanted to see it there is a better way.

Comment: Yes, also you can add it as an If clause above the BindingSource and eliminate the whole creating of the objects. But I think your patch is fine too.

Comment: This is for explanation purpose, BindingSource, ComboBox and Dictionary are member of the form itself.